# Multiple JLists make 2 of them selectable

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have mulitple JLists with single selection in an array. I want to add ListSelectionListener which should provide that only 2 Lists are selectable.
I have no idea how I can do this. Looping trought them but looking for what?

thank you for help

update: Now I make this code. When I run it like below in MouseListener, everthing is working well, but when I run it in ListSelectionListener it is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
public class TblManagement extends JInternalFrame {


JList<String> lastListSelected = null;
    .
    .

    public TblManagement(JDesktopPane desk) {

    MouseInputAdapter listMouseHandler = new ListMouseHandler();

    // create JLists.
    columnslist[i].addMouseListener(listMouseHandler);

    }

    private class ListMouseHandler extends MouseInputAdapter {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        JList<String> currentListSelected = (JList<String>) e.getSource();

        int selectedIndex = currentListSelected.getSelectedIndex();
        String selectedValue = currentListSelected.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIndex);

        //System.out.println(selectedValue);

        clearSelections(mainPanel, currentListSelected, lastListSelected);
        lastListSelected = currentListSelected;
        System.out.println(lastListSelected.getModel().getElementAt(0));

    }
}

        void clearSelections(Container container, JList currentListSelected, JList lastListSelected) {

    for (Component c : container.getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JList) {
            if ( c != lastListSelected && c != currentListSelected) {
             System.out.println("JList found");
             ((JList) c).clearSelection();

            }
        }

        else
            if (c instanceof Container) {
               clearSelections((Container)c, currentListSelected, lastListSelected);
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Looping trought them but looking for what?` if you don't know what you are looking for how do you expect us to know what you are looking for? Only you know what the function of each JList is. Why do you add the JLists to an Array? Just add the ListSelectionjListener to the JList when you create the JList.

Comment: My problem is, that I don't know what the ListSelectionListener should do to make only 2 JLists selectable.